# joomla 3.2 generates item ids as css classes in the html output of e.g. menu elements, is this of any use to me or just ignore it?

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.2

I am used to develop simple, e.g. leave away whatever you don't need. This is why I have a bit a hard time with projects like joomla, because they ship with a lot of things I don't know what it should be good for. 
Someone knows why these classes are added to the elements?
are they of any use to me?

[image: an example of the generated item ids that are added]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark Simpson said, they're not actually used.

If you wish to remove them, go to line 25 of `modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php` and you will find this:

```
$class = 'item-'.$item->id;
```

which you can simply change to:

```
$class = '';
```

Do note that if you do edit this file, it may get overridden in a Joomla update and thus your changes will be lost. So instead of editing this core file, make a [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Answer (score 2):

The cms doesn't use them. Those are just helper classes, there for the benefit of template designers and site builders.

Say you want to highlight a particular menu item by giving it a different color. You could do this:

```
.item-435 a {color: red} /* turn that particular menu item red */
```

Comment: those IDs are actually saved in the DB, right? so when I want to move the local development to the production site, I first have to figure out what tables I have to move along from local development.

Comment: @Toskan Or do what most people do and use AkeebaBackup or some other backup extension to make a copy of your development site and then deploy it to your production site.